# Why the bytecode is different for string multiplication?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-optimization, cpython, python-internals

I was playing around with strings and came across the following behavior:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('"abcdefgh" * 513')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('abcdefgh')
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (513)
              4 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              6 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis('"abcdefgh" * 512')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('abcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefgh')
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see when I multiply `"abcdefgh"` with `512`, python pre-computing the complete string during the compilation phase, But when I change the number to `513` it no longer doing that, Instead it generates two `LOAD_CONST` and  `BINARY_MULTIPLY` opcodes(In other terms python no longer pre-computing the result during the compilation phase).
Could someone explain the reason for this behavior?.

NOTE: I know from the code perspective it works fine, but I am curios to know the reason for this behavior.

Comment: This is probably an implementation-specific optimization. In theory, *any* expression involving constants could be evaluated to a constant at compile-time. In this case, there appears to simply be a hard-coded limit to how "big" an expression can be before it is simply left to be evaluated at run time instead.

Comment: I *think* the relevant function in CPython is https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/eaccc12aa986f92ea05f3f0a63cedbff78dd67f1/Python/compile.c#L3849, although it's not obvious to me where the decision is made to leave the expression unfolded when the integer is 513 or larger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as [*constant folding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding). You are seeing an AST optimization, specifically [`fold_binop` in `Python/ast_opt.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1e5d33e9b9b8631b36f061103a30208b206fd03a/Python/ast_opt.c#L216).

The reason there are [limits on the size](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1e5d33e9b9b8631b36f061103a30208b206fd03a/Python/ast_opt.c#L120-L123) is to prevent the AST from blocking while attempting to fold huge constants. We don't want Python to spend too much time in the parse/compile stage, that can cause problems. For example, it would mean importing this module would become very slow and memory hungry:

```
if False:
    100 ** 10000000000
print("hello world")
```

`"abcdegh" * 512` has length 4096 which is the [`MAX_STR_SIZE`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1e5d33e9b9b8631b36f061103a30208b206fd03a/Python/ast_opt.c#L122).  When you use `"abcdefgh" * 513` then the AST optimizer decides this is no longer a [`safe_multiply`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1e5d33e9b9b8631b36f061103a30208b206fd03a/Python/ast_opt.c#L126).